# Copy data from different activities in ADF and wait for all to finish before copying to dedicated table in Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, temp-tables

I have a For Each activity in azure data factory that runs **two** copy activities. Each of these copy activities have a **Synapse Dedicated pool table** as a sink (different table for each copy activity). I'm using an Upsert as the copy method.
I want for the data to be copied into their designated dedicated tables at the same time so as to not get inconsistent data.

How can I do this? Would it need a pre-copy script in ADF that checks the status of each activity or a temp table the data is dumped to prior to being pushed to the actual dedicated table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADF and Synapse Copy activities are not transaction bound and load in batches. For both tables to be consistent in loading, you would need to copy the data into staging tables and then trigger a stored procedure activity that would load the data into destination tables bound within transcation

Comment: By staging table you're just referring to a regular table not a temp one correct? Asking because the copy activity in ADF requires a table name and schema name, and I'm not sure what schema I would need to give it for a temporary table

Comment: Yes, I meant a regular table and not a temporary. You can truncate the staging tables at the end of the transcation within sp